# Finding a single missing value that yields a correlation value

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, imputation

I'm trying to impute a missing value of one variable such that it'll yield a given correlation value

```
library(MASS)
mat <- mvrnorm(49, mu = c(0,5), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.05,.05,1), ncol = 2), empirical = TRUE)

cor50row <-  function(x,y, rho){

  y_lnt <- length(y)

  x[length(x) +1] <- mean(x)

  val <- seq(-1000,0, .01)

  for(indx in val){
    y[y_lnt + 1] <- indx
    if(rho - cor(x,y) < 1e-6){
      break
    }
  }
  return(cbind(x,y))
}
a <- cor50row(x = mat[,1], y= mat[,2], rho = .06)
```

So the idea is to find the missing value of the y variable that increases the correlation by .01

Comment: What's the specific question here? Does your current function not work correctly, what results are you expecting to see?

Comment: Also, `x` and `y` will have a correlation of roughly zero the way you are generating them, and you can't change that (definitely not all the way to 0.55) by changing just a single value.

Comment: The idea is to find a missing value that increases the correlation by a value say .01. 
I've edited my code to reflect that

Comment: I don't know if this is actually possible the way you've set up the problem - because the extra `x` value you add is `mean(x)`, I think the new correlation will always be smaller than before, no matter what the new y value you add is.

Comment: @Marius What if I change the extra `x` value to `mean(x) - sd(x)`, is it possible I can write an R code that solves for the missing value of `y` even if the new correlation reduces by .01